# How do I test the performance of an SQL query with parameters in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Using ActivityMonitor, I got an SQL query that is slow.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3, 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Column1 = @parameter1 AND Column2 = @parameter2
```

How do I execute the query with specific parameter values without changing the existing execution plan?

Comment: Use [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16). That keeps both the queries and execution plans and allows you to inspect them. There are ready-made reports for expensive queries or those with high variance, multiple execution plans

Comment: ActivityMonitor keeps execution plans and queries as well.
I want to test the query with different parameters, but when I define the parameter values in SSMS -> new query, then it uses new execution plan, because the values are known

Answer (score 0):

I would guess a combination of the following query hints would do that:

1. [KEEPFIXED PLAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#keepfixed-plan)
2. Any of

   - [OPTIMIZE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#optimize-for--variable_name--unknown---literal_constant----n--)
   - [USE PLAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query#use-plan)